# htaccess not behaving for rewrite rules

Tags: html, apache, dokuwiki

I use Dokuwiki for my website. I have a quick question about htaccess rewrite rules. I have the following configuration. The suggestions come from [the Dokuwiki help](https://www.dokuwiki.org/rewrite).

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^lib/exe/xmlrpc.php$      https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^_media/(.*)              lib/exe/fetch.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^_detail/(.*)             lib/exe/detail.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^_export/([^/]+)/(.*)     doku.php?do=export_$1&id=$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^$                        doku.php  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteRule (.*)                      doku.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$               doku.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I admit that I don't understand all of what's going on. The important thing is that I want

```
http://mydomain.com
```

to be changed to

```
http://www.mydomain.com
```

and also any subdomains. Also, I want to get rid of the ugly Dokuwiki syntax, which attaches things like doku.php? to the end of links.

Currently, the transformation with this .htaccess file is:

```
[Good] www.mydomain.com --> www.mydomain.com
[Good] www.mydomain.com/mypage --> www.mydomain.com/mypage

[Bad] mydomain.com --> www.mydomain.com/doku.php
[Bad] mydomain.com/mypage --> www.mydomain.com/doku.php?id=mypage
```

so you see, it seems to work properly if I attach www in front of things, but when I don't, then the re-write rule attaches the proper www, but now the ugly wiki syntax also accompanies the site name (doku.php and id= parts).

Where did I go wrong in the htaccess configuration?

Answer (score 0):

TSGM, that looks fine except that you have the rewrite from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com as the last two lines. Move the last two line up so that they are just after `RewriteEngine on` and that should fix it.

The reason being that (sometimes) a redirect was triggered to create the 'clean urls' and when this happened the rewrite to www never gets executed.

By moving the two lines up, you are forcing the www rewrite to happen first before the doku rewrite kicks in.